# Pug template engine dropdown(select) query

Tags: javascript, pug

I’m following the local library project on MDN as in the link below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms/Create_BookInstance_form

In the project pug template engine is used for the views. In the below code, could you please explain the if and option lines under the for in loop

```js
form(method="POST" action='')
    div.form-group
      label(for='book') Book:
      select#book.form-control(type='select' placeholder='Select book' name='book' required='true')
       - book_list.sort(function(a, b) {let textA = a.title.toUpperCase(); let textB = b.title.toUpperCase(); return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;});
       for book in book_list
        if bookinstance
          option(value=book._id selected=(bookinstance.book.toString()==book._id.toString() ? 'selected' : false)) #{book.title}
        else
          option(value=book._id) #{book.title}
```

Thanks
Jag

Comment: The `if` is just pug conditional syntax(https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html). The `option` is a html tag used in the select dropdown.

Comment: sure. but what does if bookinstance mean please. also in the option tag what does selected=(bookinstance.book.toString()==book._id.toString() ? 'selected' : false) do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by Stephen in the comments

> The `if` is just pug conditional syntax(https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html). The `option` is a html tag used in the select dropdown.